# Getting an error on using react-phone-input-2 on vercel and netlify but not on local using react+vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, react-phone-input-2

Hi guys I am trying to use react-phone-input-2 in my react+vite application but it is throwing below error when i deploy it on netlify and vercel and when I am using it on local it is working fine:
[image: error on console]

This is my code:

```
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/bootstrap.css";

<div>
            <PhoneInput
              country="us"
              value={number}
              onChange={(e) => setNumber(e)}
              required
              inputStyle={{
                width: "100%",
                flex: 1,
                minWidth: "100px",
                // lineHeight: "1.5",
              }}
            />
```